# Latex list of figures as numberd reference in content table

Tags: latex

I am working on my thesis using Latex. When creating a list of figures at the end of my document I add it manualy to my list of content. This works fine, however there is no numbering. I tried several ideas but could not find a fitting suloution.

Code:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\crule[3][black]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{#2}{#3}}}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}
\graphicspath{{Images/}}
% !TeX root = /test.tex
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
%\date{12.07.2020}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\begin{document}
\include{Title}
\newpage

\include{chapter/Abstract}

\newpage
\tableofcontents


\newpage
\chapter{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}[KL-Divergence]
\acro{Adam}{Adaptive Moment Estimation}
\acro{AI}{Artificial Intelligence}
\acro{VAE}{Variational Autoencoder}
\end{acronym}

\newpage
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\listfigurename}}
\listoffigures

\newpage
\chapter{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}[KL-Divergence]
\acro{Adam}{Adaptive Moment Estimation}
\acro{AI}{Artificial Intelligence}
\acro{VAE}{Variational Autoencoder}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

This results in:

```
1. Acronyms
List of Figures
2. Acronyms
```

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Koma script has the `listof=totocnumbered` option to get a numbered list of figures in the table of contents:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,bibliography=totocnumbered,listof=totocnumbered]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\crule[3][black]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{#2}{#3}}}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}
\graphicspath{{Images/}}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
%\date{12.07.2020}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\begin{document}
%\include{Title}
\newpage

%\include{chapter/Abstract}

\newpage
\tableofcontents


\newpage
\chapter{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}[KL-Divergence]
\acro{Adam}{Adaptive Moment Estimation}
\acro{AI}{Artificial Intelligence}
\acro{VAE}{Variational Autoencoder}
\end{acronym}

\newpage
\cleardoublepage
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\listfigurename}}
\listoffigures

\newpage
\chapter{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}[KL-Divergence]
\acro{Adam}{Adaptive Moment Estimation}
\acro{AI}{Artificial Intelligence}
\acro{VAE}{Variational Autoencoder}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

[image]